# Convert data to Json in CodeIgniter with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am struggling to convert json code in CodeIgniter, i wanna make pagination.

I am using ajax and want to controle data convert to json and send it to view. I can someone explain me how to do that.

Code in controler, instead foreach part i am trying to make Json, and send it to view

```
function ajax(){

    $rpp= $_POST['rpp'];
    $last = $_POST['last'];
    $pn =  $_POST['pn'];

        if($pn<1){
            $pn=1;
        }
        elseif($pn>$last){
            $pn =$last;
        }

        $l = ($pn - 1) * $rpp;
        $this->db->limit($l, $rpp);
        $row = $this->db->get('pages');

        $dataString='';
        foreach($row->result() as $r){
            $id = $r->id;
            $info = $r->info;
            $dataString .= $id.'|'.$info.'||';

        }

            echo json_encode($dataString);
    }
}
```

**view part**

```
function request_page(pn)
{ 
    var rpp = <?php echo $rpp; ?>; // results per page
    var last = <?php echo $last; ?>; // last page number

    var results_box = document.getElementById("results_box");
    var pagination_controls = document.getElementById("pagination_controls");
    results_box.innerHTML = "loading results ...";
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('search/ajax')?>",
                data: { 'rpp' : rpp , 'last' : last, 'pn' : pn},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                 // alert(msg)
                 ;
                  var dataArray = msg.split("||");
            var html_output = "";
            for(i = 0; i < dataArray.length - 1; i++){
                var itemArray = dataArray[i].split("|");
                html_output += "ID: "+itemArray[0]+" - Testimonial from <b>"+itemArray[1]+"</b><hr>";
            }
             results_box.innerHTML = html_output;
                }


            });

    var paginationCtrls = "";

    if(last != 1){
        if (pn > 1) {
            paginationCtrls += '<button onclick="request_page('+(pn-1)+')">&lt;</button>';
        }
        paginationCtrls += ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <b>Page '+pn+' of '+last+'</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        if (pn != last) {
            paginationCtrls += '<button onclick="request_page('+(pn+1)+')">&gt;</button>';
        }
    }
    pagination_controls.innerHTML = paginationCtrls;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy

you should have a view to encode the data to json. Its just this:

```
<?php
    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($json);
```

In the controller you just have to load this view with an array as parameter (i think that stdClass is also valid):

```
    $data['json'] = array("foo" => "bar", "bar" => "foo");
    $this->load->view('your_json_view', $data);
```

Comment: should i remove foreach loop and $row = $this->db->get('pages');       json_encode($row);

Comment: i think each row is a std class. Add it to an array and test if it gets converted. If its not, then load each row into an associative array and send it as parameter. I mean:
$myArray['json'] = array();
foreach($row->result() as $r) { array_push($myArray['json'], $r);}
$this->load->view('yourView', $myArray);

Comment: @ZeljkoKovacevic the example I sent in the response (array("foo" => "bar", "bar" => "foo");) will be transformed in msg.foo == "bar" and msg.bar == "foo"